# problem with jquery live submit

Tags: jquery, livequery

I am trying to bind the submit function to a number of forms in my page, but the problem is they still keep submitting the form!

I tried these:

```
$(".toggle-form-submit").parents("form").live("submit", function(e){
  var myForm = $(this);
  console.log(myForm);

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

**SUBMITS FORM**

```
live("submit"...

livequery("submit"...
```

**WORKS AS INTENDED**

```
 submit(function()...
```

why doesn't it work if it is live or even livequery?

Comment: Though it's not a real answer to your question, a workaround would be to bind to the click event of your submit button.

Comment: i tried that but this is in relation to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374322/ie-problem-with-getting-ajax-html-response/5374348#5374348

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to `.live()`. Rather, the `.live()` method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

So you need a selector that selects those forms, using `parents()` won't work.